# Android Manifest error on import new gradle project

Tags: android

I received the below error on gradle build:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

My app gradle file

Comment: post your manifest and gradle code

Comment: post your log details

Comment: meanwhile you can try to clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Check your Build variants,and also the keystore paths in build.gradle(Module:app) file.

Comment: @AMAN SINGH ::: I tired clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Please post your log here, and check the gradle.properties Xxx values

Comment: Thanks all solved the issue "use same launcher icon for both manifest file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all solved the issue "use same launcher icon for both manifest file"